# HTML Extend left bar to bottom of scrolling webpage

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am trying to make a left bar on my website.  Currently, it only extends to the bottom of the visible window.  If I scroll down on the webpage, the bottom edge of the left bar shows.  In other words, it doesn't go all the way to the bottom of the page.  I need this left bar to scroll with the webpage, but also go all the way to the bottom.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
div.sideBar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 210px;
    width: 18%;
}
```

I also have a canvas fixed in the background of the webpage:

```
<canvas id="backgroundCanvas" style="display:block; position:fixed;
    width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0"></canvas>
```

After that, my side bar:

```
<div class="sideBar">  Some links are here </div>
```

Then, the main part of my webpage, which extends down far past the bottom of the screen:

```
<div style="position:relative; z-index:1; width:1100px;
    max-width: calc(65% - 40px); height:100%; margin:0 auto;">

    500 lines of text that you need to scroll down to see.
    The left bar should extend all the way to the bottom of this.
</div>
```

I have tried using left, right, top, bottom set to 0, and it didn't seem to work.  I tried position:fixed too, but this it not what I am looking for.  The left bar should scroll with the rest of the page normally (as if it were attached), but also extend all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Code is:

```css
div.sideBar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 210px;
    width: 25%;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* or auto */
}
```

```html
<div class="sideBar">  Some links are here</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but that is not what I meant by "scrolling with the rest of the page".  Overflow-y: scroll puts a scroll bar on the left bar.  I meant for it to scroll as if it was attached to the rest of the page, so there is only one scroll bar at the right of the screen.  The overflowing text is not in the left bar, but in the central part of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.sideBar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 210px;
    width: 18%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

Comment: As I said for Rafiqul Islam's answer, I'm not trying to get a scroll bar on the left bar.  I also mentioned in the question that position:fixed is not what I am looking for.  It should not be fixed relative to the browser window, but fixed relative to the scrolling webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I reluctantly resorted to JavaScript to solve the problem.  I used the following bit of code to set the height of the left bar to the maximum webpage height just after the webpage loads:

```
var body = document.body;
var html = document.documentElement;
var leftBar = document.getElementById("sideBar");
function setLeftbarHeight() {
    var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
               html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
    leftBar.style.height = height + "px";
}
//slight delay before setting the height of the left bar because
//  it may take a split second before the full length of the page is loaded
setTimeout(function(){
    setLeftbarHeight();
}, 200);
setTimeout(function(){
    setLeftbarHeight();
}, 600);
```